# Etale algebras over dual numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How to classify all etale algebras over $k[x]/x^2$ where $k$ is some field? All etale covers? What is the classification for an arbitrary Artin algebra?

My attempt: Let's first assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. Let $k[x]/x^2 \to A$ be an etale map. Then $k \to A \otimes_{k[x]/x^2} k$ is etale. Therefore, $A/x = \Pi_{i \in I} k$ where $|I|$ is the degree of $A$. Does it follow that $A = \Pi_{i \in I} k[x]/x^2$? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I mean, this makes intuitive sense from the topological perspective. You probably need to mumble something about how lack of ramification implies that the components of $\operatorname{Spec}A/x$ "spread out" to copies of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ without intersecting.

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, that makes sense but I don't see how to make it rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can just do this explicitly, but I thought I'd mention that there is a nice aspect of the theory that makes the comments from above precise. The key thing that makes everything nice is the topological invariance of the etale site:

> **Theorem(Topological invariance of the etale site, [Tag 04DZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DZ)):** *Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a universal homeomorphism. Then, the pullback functor $(V\to Y)\mapsto (V\times_Y X\to X)$ defines an equivalence of categories
> $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\text{Schemes etale}\\ \text{over }Y\end{matrix}\right\}\to \left\{\begin{matrix}\text{Schemes etale}\\ \text{over }X\end{matrix}\right\}.$$

In particular, as $\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to \mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$ is a universal homeomorphism (being a nilpotent closed immersion) we see that the functor

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\text{Schemes etale}\\ \text{over }\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))\end{matrix}\right\}\to \left\{\begin{matrix}\text{Schemes etale}\\ \text{over }\mathrm{Spec}(k)\end{matrix}\right\}.$$

is an equivalence. Now, as you are certainly well-aware, the etale algebras over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ are of the form $\bigsqcup_i\mathrm{Spec}(L_i)$ with $L_i/k$ a finite etale extension. As $\bigsqcup_i \mathrm{Spec}(L_i[x]/(x^2))$ pulls back along $\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to \mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$ to $\bigsqcup_i\mathrm{Spec}(L_i)$ we deduce that, up to isomorphism, every etale scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$ is isomorphic to such a $\bigsqcup_i \mathrm{Spec}(L_i[x]/(x^2))$.

Comment: Oh, sure, I'm an idiot! That makes a lot of sense!